# Non-ejected Time Machine external HDD no longer connects to Mac

Tags: mac, troubleshooting, external-hard-drive, time-machine, eject

I accidentally unplugged (without ejecting) my formatted external Seagate HDD I've been using happily as a Time Machine on my Mac. Now the disk itself isn't recognised by the computer, and the light on the drive just pulsates.

Any ideas how to get it hooked up again?

Comment: Stupid question: did you turn the drive off and on again? Did you reboot the Mac?

Comment: I've done all the usual thing: restart Mac, unconnect/reconnect HDD, power on/off everything etc.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when disconnecting a drive without ejecting it, the drive's integrity is checked upon the next connection. If there are many files on the disk, or the disk is large, this can take some time.

Just leave the drive connected overnight, most likely it will resolve itself.

Comment: Well it has many GB of data from my Time Machine back-up, so that could be a reason. However the icon for the drive doesn't show up on the desktop like any other HDD I connect. Should it matter? Even so I'll leave it for a while and see what happens :)

Comment: Yes, for me it sometimes takes more than 30 Minutes for the icon to show up on the Desktop. It shows up in the Disk Utility Program, however.

Answer (score 1):

You may have screwed up the directory structure of the drive by not ejecting it. If Disk Utility can't repair it I would suggest trying [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/Diskwarrior/index.html).